# XAML : have the current color of an element in a storyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, storyboard, winrt-xaml

is it possible to get the current color of the element

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="SBFade">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="keyframes" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF681D1D"/>
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Gray"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#808080" >.....</Grid>
```

At the line where the value is #FF681D1D, I would like to have the current background color of the Grid (this color can change during the runtime..
thank for any help !

Comment: Instead of fetching the background color you could try to use "Transaparent" and see if you get the same effect.

Comment: It's a good idea ! But when I try this, the grid becomes transparent to Gray.. I'm looking to a fade from the actual color to Gray

Comment: Did you try Value="{Binding Background, ElementName=LayoutRoot} ?

Comment: It is a very good idea but, oddly enough, it's a black effect !?

Comment: is it possible to add x:NAme="StartColor" in the first EasingColorKeyFrame  and in C# have a access at the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the non-keyframe animation, omitting the "From" value will do what you want.

something like:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="SBFade">
    <ColorAnimation x:Name="keyframes" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.6" />
</Storyboard>
```

alternatively, with keyframes, if you omit the early/first keyframe, you get the same effect.  using anything other than DiscreteColorKeyFrame (which jumps to the specified color at the specified time without interpolation) will interpolate between colors.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="SBFade">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="keyframes" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Gray"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

these are very similar to the msdn examples [ColorAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation.aspx) and [ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimationusingkeyframes.aspx) (scroll down to the xaml examples).

if you want to write the reverse animations (un-fading from Gray to whatever color), maintain the desired color in a viewmodel, and bind the To property (in the case of non-keyframe animations) or the Value property (in the case of keyframe animations) to that property of the viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks !! Just omitting the "From"  and it's nice !!